# Google Games Services Display Orientation

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services, orientation

I'm developing a game using LibGDX and I'm using `BaseGameUtils` to implement Play Games Services in it. It's working very well. But my game is in landscape mode, so when I call leaderboard or achievements it opens up in landscape mode. I don't want that. I want the games services to open in portrait only. There's no entry of BaseGameUtils in my manifest file and I checked the Android Manifest file in BaseGameUtils module, but there's no `<activity>` in there.

How can I change the orientation when games services is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Try `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` in your activity.

Comment: Okay I'll try this.